# Jquery выборка

Tags: jquery

css:

```
table.menu {border-collapse:collapse;}
table.menu td {border: 1px #4682B4 solid;background-color:#B0C4DE;opacity: 0.5;}
```

html:

```
<table class='menu' width='100px'>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 1</a></td>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 2</a></td>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 3</a></td>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 4</a></td>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 5</a></td>
        <tr><td><a href='#'>Link 6</a></td>
    </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        var def = $("#menu td").css("opacity");
        $("#menu td").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 200);
            },
            function () {
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity:  def}, 200);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Этот код не работает. Как сделать правильно выборку (если просто td работает)? Также вопрос. Как сделать такую же выборку, только + выборка по thead/tbody?

Comment: попробуйте ``$("#menu > td")``

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Тогда установите вашим td-шкам нужный класс и используйте его как селектор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну так вы же выборку делаете по id, а таблица содержит класс! Т.е. нужно

```
$(".menu td")
```

Comment: До чего же всё банально...

Comment: ах точно) спасибо большое)

Comment: Пометьте ответ как правильный, что бы не висел в не отвеченных.